# Не удается вставить данные в PostgreSQL из Telegram бота

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Я пишу телеграм-бота и хочу вставить текст сообщения пользователя в базу данных. База данных содержит таблицу «User» с двумя полями («firstname» и «lastname») со значением:

> allowNull: false.

Но сейчас я не могу вставить текст сообщения в базу данных. Сообщение об ошибке отсутствует. Что я сделал не так?

```
bot.on('message', async msg => {
    if (msg.text === 'Start') {
      await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Enter your firstname", {
        reply_markup: {
          keyboard: [
            ['Next']
          ]
        }
      })
      if (msg.text !== "Start") {
        const firstname = msg.text
        await User.create({firstname: `${firstname}`})
      }
    }

    if (msg.text === 'Next') {
        await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Enter your lastname")
        if (msg.text !== "Next") {
          const lastname = msg.text
          await User.create({lastname: `${lastname}`})
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас 2 столбца в таблице (firstname и lastname), и оба не могут быть пустыми (`allowNull: false`), то при создании пользователя вам нужно указать не только firstname, но и lastname:

```js
await User.create({firstname: `${firstname}`, lastname: "Test Lastname"})
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за то, что ответили. Вы единственный человек, который отозвался. Я объясню подробнее как на самом деле устроен бот. В таблице имеется 10 столбцов с разными названиями и имеется 10 таких же условий. То есть, в каждом таком условии мне дописывать все 10 столбцов?

Comment: Я отредактировал, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: На самом деле, условия `allowNull: false` нужно только для обязательных полей. Если поле может быть не указано, то следует сделать `allowNull: true`